# NodeJS/Mongoose: Array is getting empty after pushing values in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using **Mongoose Reference Schema** and trying to get all entities of the current user, and pushing it to the array, but after forEach loop ends, **the array is getting empty**

```
let entityList = [];

Entity.find({})
      .populate('host')
      .exec( function(err, entities)
      {
            //Iterate through each entity, find if it belongs to current user
            //If it belongs, add to the list
            entities.forEach((entity)=>
            {
                  console.log(entity);
                  console.log(entity.host._id);
                  if(entity.host._id == req.params.id){
                        console.log("Found");
                        entityList.push(entity);
                        console.log(entityList);    //Printing the value
                  }
            });
      });
//Not being logged
entityList.forEach((i)=>{
      console.log(i);
});
console.log(entityList); //Empty array
```

**EntitySchema:**

```
const entitySchema = new Schema({
      username: String,
      userType: String,
      host: { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
      }
});

const Entity = mongoose.model("Entity",entitySchema);
```

**UserSchema:**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
      socialMediaID: String,
      username: String,
      thumbnail: String
});

const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exec()` function returns immediately. Your code continues with logging `entityList`. But at that time the list is still empty.

The callback, which fills `entityList`, is called sometimes later (asynchronously).